# Manipulate UserDefined tag (TXXX frame) with Taglib-Sharp

Tags: powershell, taglib-sharp

### Situation & Task

I have a large music collection and I want to clean their [ID3V2 tags](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) with PowerShell and [taglip-sharp](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/). Some tags like `comment` or `encoding` should be deleted while others like `artist` or `title` should not.

[Usually you manipulate ID3 tags this way (Simplified version)](http://tomorrow.uspeoples.org/2013/02/powershell-id3-tag-editing-via-taglib.html)

```
# Add taglib dll 
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$PSScriptRoot\taglib-sharp.dll")

# Load example mp3 into memory as [taglib.file]
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\path\to\musicFile.mp3")

# Change comment tag 
$media.tag.tags[0].Comment = "Hello World"

# Save tags back to mp3 file
$Media.Save()
```

### Problem

Many music files store custom information like `URL` or `Shop Name` in a frame [called `TXXX`](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames). Unfortunately, this frame is not accessible with the method shown above. Or I haven't found a way yet.

Instead you use

```
# Read UserTextInformationFrame
$media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2).GetFrames("TXXX")
```

This [User defined text information frame](http://fossies.org/dox/f-spot-0.8.2/classTagLib_1_1Id3v2_1_1UserTextInformationFrame.html) can hold multiple values. And some are useful since music players like Foobar store `PERFORMER`, `DATE` or `replay_track_gain` tags in `TXXX`.

Example output for the line above could be:

```
Description  : replaygain_track_gain
Text         : {-5.00 dB}
FieldList    : {-5.00 dB}
TextEncoding : Latin1
FrameId      : {84, 88, 88, 88}
Size         : 32
Flags        : None
GroupId      : -1
EncryptionId : -1

Description  : URL
Text         : {www.amazon.com}
FieldList    : {www.amazon.com}
TextEncoding : UTF16
FrameId      : {84, 88, 88, 88}
Size         : 43
Flags        : None
GroupId      : -1
EncryptionId : -1
```

After this, I was able to filter out all unnecessary TXXX values

```
# Create a whitelist of TXXX frames
$goodTXXX  = 'performer','replaygain_track_gain','date'

# Read UserTextInformationFrame AND filter it
$newTXXX = $Media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2).GetFrames("TXXX") | 
  where { $goodTXXX -contains $_.Description }
```

### Question: How to write multiple values to `TXXX` frame

So my question is, how do I save my filtered results back to mp3 file?
My failed attempts were:

```
$media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2).RemoveFrames("TXXX")
$media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2).SetTextFrame("TXXX",$newTXXX)
# Removes old values, but does not show anything in Foobar

#$media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2).GetFrames("TXXX").SetText("Hello World")
# Shows garbage in Foobar. And it's not usable for multiple values
```

[Taglib-Sharp documentation for SetTextFrame](http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.3.0/classTagLib_1_1Id3v2_1_1Tag_816997f941cde1e9fbd19e60f3673b70.html)

---

**Bonus question:** Is taglib-sharp able to strip out Id3v1 and ID3v2.4 tags while saving new tags as ID3v2.3 tags? ([Related SO answer, but doesn't distinguish between v2.3 and v2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438523/taglib-sharp-not-editing-rating))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way with try & error. It's not elegant since you have to remove all TXXX values and add them back if you just want to change a single one

```
# Add taglib dll 
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$PSScriptRoot\taglib-sharp.dll")

# Load example mp3 into memory as [taglib.file]
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\path\to\musicFile.mp3")

# Get or create the ID3v2 tag.
[TagLib.Id3v2.Tag]$id3v2tag = $media.GetTag([TagLib.TagTypes]::Id3v2, 1)

# Create new 'TXXX frame' object
$TXXXFrame = [TagLib.Id3v2.UserTextInformationFrame]("WWW")

# Delete complete TXXX frame first, or else all values are just appended
$id3v2tag.RemoveFrames("TXXX")

# Set the value/text in the newly created TXXX frame, default Text encoding is UTF8
# Use curly brackets instead of single quotation marks
$TXXXFrame.Text = {www.myurl.com}

# Add TXXX frame to tag
$id3v2tag.AddFrame($TXXXFrame)

# Write all changed tags back to file
$media.Save()
```