# Taglib not saving full tags

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, taglib-sharp

I'm using taglib# to input mp3 title and artist names as metadata parsed from file names. To do this, I'm essentially looping through a list of file names, parsing the names, creating a taglib file, changing the tags, then saving and disposing of the taglib file. Oddly enough, in my circumstances, I noticed that there seems to be a maximum length for strings that tags can take as input **after** the first file has been successfully changed.

Here is a small scale example I am running now.

```
foreach (string path in files)
{
    using (TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path))
    {
        f.Tag.Title = "000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555"
        f.Save();
    }
}
```

As output, the first file touched has the correct title field:

```
000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555
```

But each file after it only has a portion:

```
000000000011111111112222222222
```

You can see it in explorer:

[image: Each title field after the first is cut short.]

The results are the same no matter the field modified. Also, explicitly calling Dispose() on the taglib file does not change anything. Why could this be?

Comment: Title, album and artist have a limit of 30 chars in the old tag format, 60 in the newer.  Maybe the files have different tag versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I always ask a question right when I'm on the brink of finding an answer. I did a little more digging and found that **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703855/2247607)** also solves my problem. In short, make sure that the right version of Id3 is in use.

*Aside: I found that this also solved another issue I was having with unicode being turned into question marks in the output. A nice bonus!*